# Diameter of a cylinder?

Tags: geometry

I'm not gifted in math, or geometry or algebra for that matter. So this will probably be a simple question for any of you here.

I especially enjoyed the length of a toilet roll question, but my Google search question which delivered this interesting site is this:

Given a cylinder with r3" and a sheet of material .25" thick and 84" long,  what is the total diameter D of the cylinder when the sheet is rolled completely around it?

Application of this question is to construct a pull down curtain of soundproof material in a hallway and I need to determine how large a container I need in which the entirety will be able to be suspended. The center of the core cylinder will be attached to a spring to raise the curtain with a ratcheting locking mechanism on the side to hold it down while in use.

Comment: It is a 2d-problem in disguise. Impose that the area of the rope equals the area of a circle sector and profit.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to consider that the wrap will form an annulus with inner radius of $3$ inches.  The area of the outer circle is then $9\pi+0.25\cdot 84=21+9\pi$ square inches.  The radius of the outer circle is then $\sqrt{\frac {21}{\pi}+9}\approx 3.96 $ inches and the diameter is twice this or about $7.92$ inches.